# Add observer for a boolean value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, observer-pattern

I am trying to add an observer to an object and trigger it by changing it boolean value.

Code:
Add Observer:

```
[unitsCellViewController.cell addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"unit" options:0 context:nil];
```

In the object, when the textfield is changing, I will change the boolean value and try to trigger the notification:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string length] != 0)
    {
        NSRange match = [@"0123456789" rangeOfString:string];
        if (match.location == NSNotFound) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"unit"];
    self.on = !on;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"unit"];

    return YES;
}
```

but this is not working, the value did get changed, but the observer is not triggered.
Am I doing this correctly? If not, how can I trigger the event when the textfield is changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a property, and override the setter

In your .h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myFlag;
```

In your .m

```
@implementation

@synthesize myFlag = _myFlag;
...
..
.


- (void)setMyFlag:(BOOL)myFlag
{
if(myFlag != _myFlag){
_myFlag = myFlag;
[self postNotification];
}
}


-(void)postNofitication
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"nameOfNotification" object:nil];
}
```

And you perform an action just when the value of the flag change.

Hope this can help.

Comment: I am a little confused. What action am I suppose to perform in mySelector to trigger the notification?

Comment: The action you need/want. A selector or a notification. [self mySelector] is just representative. You can code whatever you need in there.

Comment: i have function "- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
       ofObject:(id)object
      change:(NSDictionary *)change
        context:(void *)context". I want this to get triggered, but i don't know how to do it...

Comment: I've just edited the answer to let it more clear. It just an example. You can use notifications or the delegate approach.

Comment: Elegant solution! we don't even have to worry about unregistering the observer!

Comment: @Robaczek Fixed. Appreciate it C: